# Combining equal_range with bind2nd and binary_function

Tags: c++, stl

I have a sorted collection of

```
class Thing
{
public:
   item a;
   item b;
   other data;
};

vector<Thing> Things;
```

using

```
class MultiValuedComparator
{
public:
   item a;
   item b;

   MultiValuedComparator(item c, item d)
   {
      a = c;
      b = d;
   }
};
```

Since I have duplicates of item a, and item b (but not other data), I want to grab a range of those data structures that match item a AND item b.  The collection is sorted by item a only.

I thought equal_range would be an appropriate method to do this.  Since I needed to match more than one item I inherited from binary_function.

```
struct RangeByA : public std::binary_function<Thing, MultiValuedComparator>
{
   bool operator()(const Thing &left, const MultiValuedComparator &right)
   {
      return left.a == right.a && left.b == right.b;
   }
}
```

I don't know how to write the equal_range function so it does this.  I tried:

```
void somefunction()
{
   typedef pair<vector<Thing>::iterator, 
                vector<Thing>::iterator> startEndIterPair;

   MultiValuedComparator mvc(1, 2);

   startEndIterPair p = equal_range
      (
      Things.start(), 
      Things.end(), 
      std::bind2nd(RangeByA, mvc)
      );
}
```

but this code complains of no match for 'operator<' in '__middle.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator .. etc at the call to equal_range

How do I write this so equal_range will work?  I have no idea where to place the overloaded operator.  RangeByA does not seem to accept it.

Comment: what does MultiValuedComparator do (or u want it to do)?

Comment: YeenFei: It just holds values that I want to search for in vector<Thing> as part of my functor.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be causing a problem, but it should be `std::binary_function<Thing, MultiValuedComparator, bool>`. `binary_function` takes three template parameters.

Comment: Also, I don't think that you can use `equal_range` for this unless you sort the array based on item a and item b because `equal_range` expects the data to be sorted when it uses binary search. If you don't have it sorted by item b as well, then you could get a range that has items within it that don't match the ends with respect to items a and b.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of a comparator for equal_range is a strict weak ordering (not equality).  In addition, the comparator must be able to be called with the arguments in both orders:

```
comparator(*iter, value); // items less than lower bound
comparator(value, *iter); // items greater than upper bound
```

The result of equal_range, then, is the range of iterators where both of these calls return `false`.

A simple adjustment, then, is to add a constructor to your MultiValuedComparator that accepts a Thing, allowing a Thing object to be converted to a MultiValuedComparator object for comparison:

```
class MultiValuedComparator
{
public:
   item a;
   item b;

   MultiValuedComparator(item c, item d)
   {
      a = c;
      b = d;
   }

   MultiValuedComparator(const Thing &thing)
   {
      a = thing.a
      b = thing.b
   }
};
```

And then adjust your comparator to only use MultiValuedComparator and to use a strict weak ordering:

```
struct RangeByA : public std::binary_function<MultiValuedComparator, MultiValuedComparator>
{
   bool operator()(const MultiValuedComparator &left, const MultiValuedComparator &right)
   {
      // Sorted by a first, then b if necessary
      return (left.a < right.a)
              || (!(right.a < left.a) && (left.b < right.b)));
   }
};
```

An alternative to the above, which will avoid copies (from Thing to MultiValuedComparator),  is to simply implement `operator()` in both directions (Thing vs. MultiValuedComparator and MultiValuedComparator vs. Thing), dropping the inheritance of `std::binary_function` (not needed here):

```
struct RangeByA
{
   bool operator()(const Thing &left, const MultiValuedComparator &right) {
      // ... (same body as above)
   }

   bool operator()(const MultiValuedComparator &left, const Thing &right) {
      // ... (same body as above)
   }
};
```